# dplyr solution to group and count occurence of selected values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data such as this:

```
       inpput <- read_table2("id    genre   rank    gamewin
1   R.B 1   0
1   Pop NA  0
1   Hip.Hop 5   0
1   Pop 1   0
1   Rock    1   0
1   R.B 15  0
1   Hip.Hop 1   0
1   Electronic  1   0
1   Electronic  1   0
1   Hip.Hop 1   0
1   Pop 1   0
1   Rock    NA  0
1   Electronic  NA  0
1   Pop 1   0
1   gameWin gameWin game-restart
1   Rap NA  0
1   Rock    NA  0
1   Pop NA  0
1   Electronic  NA  0
1   R.B NA  0
1   Rap 5   0
1   Pop 5   0
1   Hip.Hop 5   0
1   Pop 1   0
1   Rap NA  0
1   gameWin gameWin game-restart
")
```

I would like to create a data frame such as this,

1. A variable "game". Indicating the game number for each ID. Each new game is identified by the "gameWin" flag. When ever gameWin=="game-restart", a new game is initiated. Although there is only one ID in the sample dataset, there are many more in the real one.
2. A variable "gamewinrank<10", that counts the cases where the variable rank equals 1 or rank<=10 for unique genres. So if "rank=1" for hip
   hop, twice, within the same game, it is only counted once.

   3) A variable "gamewin_rank1", that counts the cases where rank=1 for unique genres. So within a game-ID (grouped by game,id) if rank=1 for rap and rank=1 for
   rock, the field would output 2. Likewise, within a game-ID, rank=1 for rap, rank=1 for rock and another rank=1 for rock, the field would still output two.

The output should look like this:

```
output <- read_table2("id   genre   rank    gamewin game    gamewin_rank<10 gamewin_rank1
1   R.B 1   0   1       
1   Pop NA  0   1       
1   Hip.Hop 5   0   1       
1   Pop 1   0   1       
1   Rock    1   0   1       
1   R.B 15  0   1       
1   Hip.Hop 1   0   1       
1   Electronic  1   0   1       
1   Electronic  1   0   1       
1   Hip.Hop 1   0   1       
1   Pop 1   0   1       
1   Rock    NA  0   1       
1   Electronic  NA  0   1       
1   Pop 1   0   1       
1   gameWin gameWin game-restart    1   5   5
1   Rap NA  0   2       
1   Rock    NA  0   2       
1   Pop NA  0   2       
1   Electronic  NA  0   2       
1   R.B NA  0   2       
1   Rap 5   0   2       
1   Pop 5   0   2       
1   Hip.Hop 5   0   2       
1   Pop 1   0   2       
1   Rap NA  0   2       
1   gameWin gameWin game-restart    2   3   1
")
```

I've thought about using case_when and mutate to accomplish this, but I don't know how to possibly identify the unique occurrence of a genre within the stipulated rank, any help appreciated!

Comment: Output won't parse for me. Can you use `dput` to output it?

Comment: Oh, yeah, your output table isn't complete. It's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for because there are only 5 entries for non-gameWin rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a complete output, it's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for but this should be close:

```
input %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(rank), as.numeric) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    gamewin = gamewin == "game-restart",
    game = lag(cumsum(gamewin) + 1) %>% ifelse(is.na(.),1, .)
    ) %>%
  group_by(id,game) %>% 
  mutate( 
    'gamewin_rank<10' = case_when(
      gamewin ~ length(unique(genre[which(rank <= 10)])),
      TRUE    ~ NA_integer_),
    gamewin_rank1 = case_when(
      gamewin ~ length(unique(genre[which(rank == 1)])),
      TRUE    ~ NA_integer_)
    )
```

> A variable "game". Indicating the game number for each ID. Each new game is identified by the "gameWin" flag. When ever gameWin=="game-restart", a new game is initiated. Although there is only one ID in the sample dataset, there are many more in the real one.

We can do this easily by transforming your gamewin column to a Boolean state, which we can count and then running cumsum along it. (In general, storing 0s and then a string is going to take more memory than a Boolean column, so I recommend utilizing this elsewhere, plus you get the nice advantages of TRUEs equalling 1 for math purposes.) Since you want to add one after the gamewin pops up, we add lag, and then the `ifelse(is.na(.))` bit is to address the first value being NA because of the lagging.

> A variable "gamewinrank<10", that counts the cases where the variable rank equals 1 or rank<=10 for unique genres. So if "rank=1" for hip hop, twice, within the same game, it is only counted once.

I implemented what you asked for, but I'm not sure this is actually what you meant because you got a value of 3 and there are definitely five unique genres where the rank <= 10 (we don't need to evaluate rank == 1 because that's included in rank <= 10). Perhaps you could rephrase and I can edit this to help?

> A variable "gamewin_rank1", that counts the cases where rank=1 for unique genres. So within a game-ID (grouped by game,id) if rank=1 for rap and rank=1 for rock, the field would output 2. Likewise, within a game-ID, rank=1 for rap, rank=1 for rock and another rank=1 for rock, the field would still output two.

Same implementation as above, restricting to rank == 1.

**Edit:**
Here's what I think you're actually after re: summary statistics using summarize instead of mutate as discussed in the comments:

```
input %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(rank), as.numeric) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    gamewin = gamewin == "game-restart",
    game = lag(cumsum(gamewin) + 1) %>% ifelse(is.na(.),1, .)
  ) %>%
  group_by(id,game) %>% 
  summarize( 
    'gamewin_rank<10' = length(unique(genre[which(rank <= 10)])),
    gamewin_rank1 = length(unique(genre[which(rank == 1)])),
    hiphop = sum(genre=="Hip.Hop" & rank == 1) 
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is so elegant! I corrected my output, but basically I want the count of all unique genres within that game , for every genre that is <=10. For some reason your code gives the correct count for all those songs that are rank==1, but not for rank <=10. So for ID 1, game 2 in my example, there are 3 genres that are ranked less than one (Rap, Pop, Hip Hop), but your solution only shows a count of 1. @GenesRus

Comment: I am also trying to count the number of times hip hip had a rank of 1, with the following line added to your code: your solution%>% mutate( hiphop = case_when(
      gamewin ~ length(genre=="Hip.Hop" & final.score ==1) 
    ) However, it's not counting the occurrence correctly... any ideas?

Comment: The output still only has 5 columns for rows that aren't gameWin, but 7 for those that are, so read_table2 can't parse it. You're right...there's something weird going on with the second group. I'll see if I can solve that. Sorry for not noticing earlier!

Comment: Got it. It was a case of rank being interpreted as a <chr> instead of an int/double so the evaluation wasn't working as expected. Add in a `mutate_at(vars(rank), as.numeric) %>%` before the evaluation and it works as expected. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Be sure to call `ungroup` if you want the total numbers. Also, since you seem to want summary values with just the genre and id as identifying columns, I recommend transitioning to `summarize` instead of mutate so you can drop all the data rows and not have to mess with the case_when statement, which slows things down.

Comment: Oh, and the hip-hop example you asked about needs sum, not length, since you're doing a count of Boolean values, not looking for the length of a vector. :)